# How do I sum the a table column when the td contains text lables?

Tags: jquery, text, html-table, sum, tablecell

I am trying to sum the values of a column within a table and put that sum into another html field.  The challenge I'm running into is the values in the TD cells are simple text labels.  http://jsfiddle.net/dm4AZ/60/

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>100</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>200</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>100</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<br>
<dl>
    <dt>Total Value:</dt>
    <dd id="mySum"></dd>
</dl>


$(document).ready(function(){
     colSum();
});

function colSum() {
    var sum=0;
    //iterate through each input and add to sum
    $('myTD').each(function() {     
            sum += parseInt(this.html());                     
    }); 
    //change value of total
       $('#mySum').html(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no myTD in the markup..
Also when you want to read the value of the selector in each you need to use

**$(this)**  and not just **this**

```
 $('myTD').each(function() {     
                sum += parseInt(this.html());                     
        });
```

should be

```
$('td').each(function() {     
            sum += parseInt($(this).text());                     
    });
```

Check this [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/dm4AZ/63/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      colSum();
    });

    function colSum() {
      var sum=0;
      //iterate through each input and add to sum
      $('td').each(function() {     
        sum += parseInt($(this).text());                     
      }); 
      //change value of total
      $('#mySum').html(sum);
    }
```

Comment: this will not work.  `parseInt(this.html());` - "this" here is a DOM object, not jQuery. Has no `.html()`